# VPN for SSH, Internet for all the rest

Tags: ssh, vpn

**Intro:** Hi, I've been trying to get a VPN and ssh command to work together. And I've been successful to the point where I can get on the server with `ssh user@hostname`. But when the VPN is active, all of my internet passes trough that VPN.

**Target:** I'd like to use my own internet connection for everything other than that SSH connection.

**Option breaks SSH > VPN:**
I've noticed that there is an option "Use this connection only for resources on its network" in the "*Editing VPN"* - *"IPv4 settings"* tab - *"Routes..."* button.
It seemed like the solution, but if I enable that, I can't connect anymore with the *"ssh user@hostname"* command, it hangs till it times out.

**Thoughts:** My thoughts so far are that it does not work because the hostname(from ssh username@hostname) and the gateway(from  the VPN settings) are different. But I don't know enough about ssh or VPN to know that.

**Ideas?** Is there like an option in ssh that I am overlooking? I tried `ssh -b gatewayFromVPN username@hostname` but this didn't seem to work (and I doubt it should). Or is there an option in the VPN settings or something that could solve this?

Thanks in advance.

**Summary**

- browse etc > internet connection
- (simultaneously with)
- SSH > VPN connection

"Use this connection only for resources on its network" breaks SSH > VPN

Answer (score 3):

I have wanted to do something similar in the past. I had two ideas: split things based on port and split things based on process owner. Linux's networking system can, it transpires, handle both of these scenarios.

I asked two questions on Unix.SE. I haven't followed up on either particularly well so if you do play around, let me know what works for you.

- **By port** 
  [Only allow certain outbound traffic on certain interfaces](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12085/only-allow-certain-outbound-traffic-on-certain-interfaces)
- **By user** [Can I limit a user (and their apps) to one network interface?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/880/can-i-limit-a-user-and-their-apps-to-one-network-interface)

I dare say there is some overlap between the two techniques and that's why I mention both of them here. I've also put a large bounty on the second for some solid examples. I think splitting network connections between users is probably the most useful scenario for both of us.

Edit: I just did a Google for `iptables owner` and [found this](http://linuxpoison.blogspot.co.uk/2010/11/how-to-limit-network-access-by-user.html). This seems to suggest that a few dirty iptables lines would fix this right up. I'm still to test but it looks positively simple...

Assume you had `eth0` and `eth1` connections and you wanted user `bob` to use `eth1` and only ever use `eth1`, and force everything else onto `eth0`. This should do it...

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -m owner --uid-owner bob  -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth1 -m owner --uid-owner bob  -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth1 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -j ALLOW
```

I'm assuming you can just swap our `eth1` for your VPN connection's name and `bob` for an new user you'll create to run your ssh connection from via: `su -c ssh username@host bob`.

Answer (score 2):

After literally hours of searching, I found something simple enough.

This is technically known as **Split Tunneling** and [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/665110/1147664) you can find a perfect tutorial to do this. With **Split tunneling** you can solve the problem on a different level. You route all your work network traffic through VPN and everything else goes as normal.

I know this is not exactly the solution you wanted, but after all, It simply works.

Answer (score 1):

I have kind of achieved what I wanted by running Ubuntu virtually in Windows 7 at the moment. (Currently running VMware Player with Ubuntu 12.04)
This way my entire internet on Ubuntu is going through the VPN, but I can use my browser etc in windows 7 what doesn't have that VPN.

Though this is not what I was aiming for, it will have to do for now.

Maybe I can run Ubuntu virtually in Ubuntu or something so I don't have the need for windows in the future...

Answer (score 0):

Best way to achieve this is to define route to your ssh host via vpn gateway, default route via your internet gateway.

To further reading:

[route (8)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man8/route.8.html)