# How to fix PPTP split tunnel?

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, pptp

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 and it is fully updated. I have established the vpn connection to the host vpn server using Network Manager with PPTP.

However, when I check the "use this connection only for resources on its network" in the IPv4 routes setting I am unable to ping or resolve host names on the servers inside the host network and I have internet routes outside of the host network. When I leave the "use this connection only for resources on its network" unchecked then I am able to ping and resolve the host names but no internet routes outside of the host network.

Here is what the routes table looks like.

```
#VPN connected with "use this connection only for resources on its network" checked

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
host.ip         192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
host.ip         192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.100.180 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0


#VPN connected with "use this connection only for resources on its network" unchecked

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 ppp0
host.ip         192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
host.ip         192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.100.180 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
```

Is there anything I can do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in adding a default gateway.

When `use this connection only for resources on its network` is checked your default gateway is `192.168.1.1`. When `use this connection only for resources on its network` is unchecked your default gateway is `0.0.0.0`

Also when you are connected to `vpn` resource witch is routed trough `ppp0` interface is only one host `192.168.100.180`

In first case you can manually add route to resource on `vpn` site

```
sudo ip route add xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/yy dev ppp0
```

`xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` - represent host/network

`yy` - represent network mask

example:

add route to host `192.168.100.181` trough `ppp0`

```
 sudo ip route add 192.168.100.181/32 dev ppp0
```

add route to network range `192.168.100.0` with mask `255.255.255.0` trough `ppp0`

```
 sudo ip route add 192.168.100.0/24 dev ppp0
```

This also can be done in `Network Manager`. On same places where is `use this connection only for resources on its network` you can add route.

In second scenario, when `use this connection only for resources on its network` is unchecked you add default route to `eth0` interface. This will allow to access resources on internet

```
 sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.1
```